# How can I assign a range using array length?

Tags: arrays, bash

This is probably a silly question, more out of curiosity. I have an array in bash:

`array=(name1.ext name2.ext name3.ext)`

I want to strip off the extension from each element. I was trying to do this by looping over each element, but I was having trouble setting the range of the loop (see below):

`for i in 'echo {0..'expr ${#array[@]} - 1'}'; do 
newarray[$i]+=$(echo "${array[$i]:0:5}"); 
done`

Please note ' = "back-tick" within the code-block because I wasn't sure how to escape it.

I'm not able to just use a set range (e.g. seq 0 3), because it changes based on the folder, so I wanted to be able to use the length of the array minus 1. I was able to work around this using:

`for (( i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++ )); do
newarray[$i]+=$(echo "${array[$i]:0:5}"); done`

But I thought there should be some way to do it with the "array length minus 1" method above and wondered how I was thinking about this incorrectly. Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: To quote the `back tick` inside a "back-ticked" block, just escape the back tick, for instance, `escaped \` back tick`.

Comment: I cannot understand what you want to get and what is the problem.

Comment: What I understood is that you want to run down an array by means of a sequence of indexes, instead of increasing a counter, but I do not catch the problem.

Comment: Sorry @Jdamian I was likely not being clear in my explanation. I wasn't so concerned with the output, but rather why I was unable to use `for i in 'echo {0..'expr ${#{array[@]} - 1' ` to set an range from 0 to (array length - 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply various parameter expansion operators to each element of an array directly, without needing an explicit loop.

```
$ array=(name1.ext name2.ext name3.ext)
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]%.ext}"
name1
name2
name3
$ newarray=( "${array[@]%.ext}" )
```

In general, though, there is nearly never any need to generate a range numbers to iterate over. Just use the C-style `for` loop:

```
for ((i=0; i< ${#array[@]}; i++ )); do
    newarray[$i]="${array[i]%.ext}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks very much @chepner for the good explanation. I do have one somewhat unrelated follow-up question. I am assigning my array with a wildcard, e.g.    `array=(name*.ext)`    and then use your suggestion to strip off the extension.    However, when I call this variable later in a script:    `for i in ${newarray[@]}; do  fslcommand "$i" input output;  done`    it fails because the wildcard does not expand. Should I not be using a wildcard for array assignment?

Comment: The wildcard is expanded when you assign to `array`. However, if nothing *matches* the pattern, the array contains the literal pattern as its only element unless you set `shopt -s nullglob` previously. Make sure to quote the expansion in case any of the resulting file names contain whitespace or pattern metacharacters: `for i in "${newarray[@]}"; do`

Comment: Ok now I feel even more stupid. I wasn't setting the full path properly so of course it wasn't matching anything. Thanks for making me realize my error!

Answer (score 2):

With Bash, you could simply loop over your array elements with `${files[@]}`:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=(name1.ext name2.ext name3.ext)

for f in ${files[@]}; do
  echo "${f%.*}"
done
```

Also substring removal `${f%.*}` is a better choice if you have extensions of different lengths.

Comment: in your solution the array has just one element, thus, no `${files[@]}` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `seq` command

```
for i in `seq 0 $(( ${#array[@]} - 1 ))`
do 
      ···
done
```

or the bash brace expansion (but in this case you need `eval`):

```
for i in `eval echo {0..$(( ${#array[@]} - 1 ))}`
do 
      ···
done
```

But there is another better (it works even in sparse arrays): **let's make bash give us the array indexes**:

```
for i in ${!array[@]}
do 
      ···
done
```